# Jenkins uses sh despite being told to use bash

Tags: ios, bash, macos, shell, jenkins

I have a Jenkins instance to oversee my iOS builds, though my builds are currently failing due to the `protoc` command (to compile protobuf) not being linked in `sh`. It is however linked in `bash`, but jenkins is ignoring my directives to use `bash`.

Is there a obvious reason why? It is set both in the build script and in the master Jenkins settings - see below"

Master settings
[image: master settings]

Project build script
[image: project build script]

Jenkins is still using SH
[image: jenkins still using sh]

Comment: I wouldn't read to much into file extensions when on Linux/Unix based platforms as the extensions aren't recognised as meaning anything as it is in Windows. I'm pretty sure that the setup is the same on my Jenkins environment

Comment: @JacobKing : What makes you think that Jenkins would use sh? Your line clearly says that the script is executed by /bin/bash, so unless some malevolent admin-from-hell secretly renamed sh to bash, I don't see why  the jenkins*.sh script is run via Posix shell.